# Reasignación de variables cuando se hace clic en una opción de selección JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Espero que puedas ayudarme. Estoy intentando reasignar una variable al hacer clic en una opción con el valor especificado. No he logrado tomar el valor que está dentro de la función y puedo usarlo fuera de ella con el valor reasignado.
Específicamente, necesito usar la variable con el valor reasignado fuera de la función, no dentro
¡Gracias!
Esto es lo que tengo

```
var ActMat = "Sí"
    
   $('#selectBox').change(function(){
    if($(this).val=='Ingles'){
        ActMat="No"
    }
   })

 
    console.log(ActMat)
```

este es mi html

````
  <select id="selectBox" name="" class=" VarBtn btn btn-danger"  >
              <option  value="">Escoge tu materia</option>
              <option value="Top">Mejores Top</option>
              <option value="Ingles">Inglés</option>
              <option value="Lectura">Lectura</option>
              <option value="Matematicas">Matematícas</option>
              <option value="Sociales">Sociales</option>
              <option value="Ciencias">Ciencias</option>
      
    
            </select>```
````

Comment: El uso que mencionas (outside the function) es en el mismo formulario o posterior al submit?

Comment: Edita también el titulo de la pregunta, no solo el contenido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Te dejo una prueba funcional de lo que requieres, ya es cuestión de que lo ajustes a como lo necesitas. El botón que he agregados es para mostrarte el valor global de la variable*

*No se en que momento le das evento al select que tienes, debes tener cuidado con eso, ya que el elemento debe existir para que pueda darse el evento. En mi caso, lo hago ejecutando una función que se llama cuando se ha cargado todo el body.*

```js
var ActMat = 'SI'

function cargaInicial() {
  $('#selectBox').change(function(e) {
    ActMat = e.target.value; // asignamos el valor del elemento seleccionado
    console.log(ActMat); // mostramos en consola el valor asignado a la variable
  });
}

/**
 * Función que muestra un alert en pantalla con el valor asignado a la variable ActMat. Inicialmente su valor es SI
 */
function mostrarValorActMat() {
  alert(ActMat);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="cargaInicial()">
  <select id="selectBox" name="" class=" VarBtn btn btn-danger">
    <option value="">Escoge tu materia</option>
    <option value="Top">Mejores Top</option>
    <option value="Ingles">Inglés</option>
    <option value="Lectura">Lectura</option>
    <option value="Matematicas">Matematícas</option>
    <option value="Sociales">Sociales</option>
    <option value="Ciencias">Ciencias</option>
  </select>

  <button onclick="mostrarValorActMat();">Probar valor</button>
</body>
```

*Espero te sirva.*

Comment: Me quedo claro muchas gracias!!

Comment: @jonathanbernal vale, con gusto.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está bien, solo que cometiste un error que es la causa del mal funcionamiento. Esta línea `if($(this).val=='Ingles')` debería ser `if($(this).val()=='Ingles')`, ya que `val` es una función debes llamarla así `val()`.

Aun si arreglas esto, el console.log que tienes solo se llama una vez al cargar la página (antes de la ejecución de tu función), esto no quiere decir que el valor de la variable `ActMat` no se haya actualizado, sino que tienes que solicitar un nuevo console.log después de que el cambio haya tenido efecto.